# How to use shell regular expression in jenkinsfile for jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to replace the '/' from Git branch name with '_' in my jenkinsfile so that I can tag my docker image with the branch name. In bash the below command works fine

```
echo "${git_branch_name//\//_}"
```

But when use the above command in jenkinsfile as below it throws an error.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy

    def commit_id
    def imagetag
    def branch_name
    def git_branch_name
    node('Nodename') {

        stage('checkout') {
            checkout (scm).$Branch_Param
            sh "git rev-parse --short HEAD > .git/commit-id"
            commit_id = readFile('.git/commit-id').trim()
            sh "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > .git/branch-name"
            git_branch_name = readFile('.git/branch-name').trim()
            branch_name= sh "echo ${git_branch_name//\//_}"
            sh "echo ${commit_id}"
            sh "echo ${branch_name}"
            sh "echo Current branch is ${branch_name}"
        }

    }

WorkflowScript: 15: end of line reached within a simple string 'x' or "x" or /x/;
   solution: for multi-line literals, use triple quotes '''x''' or """x""" or /x/ or $/x/$ @ line 15, column 28.
        sh "branch_name = echo ${git_branch_name//\//_}"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I use Groovy regular expression instead of shell? why is shell not being interpreted correctly?

Thank you

Comment: I was able to get this working with groovy branch_name = git_branch_name.replaceAll("/", "_")  but I would like to know whey shell interpretation is not working

Comment: Because `sh` is the Bourne shell and not Bash, maybe? The [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) says that you can select the interpreter with a shebang line, so maybe adding `#!/bin/bash` would work? sh doesn't understand the `${parameter//pattern/replacement}` expansion, only Bash does.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're asking Groovy itself to interpret the expression `${git_branch_name//\//_}`, not the shell. Using double-quotes around the string you pass to the `sh` step is what causes that. So if you instead write the following, this first error will go away:

```java
    sh 'echo ${git_branch_name//\\//_}' // <- Note the single-quotes
```

Basically, always use single-quotes unless you specifically need to use *groovy's* string interpolation (see the very last `echo` at the bottom of this answer).

Interestingly, it seems when I tested I didn't need the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to specify bash as some comments suggest; this `${variable//x/y}` replace syntax worked in an sh step as-is. I guess the shell spawned was bash. I don't know if that's always the case, or if our Jenkins box has been specifically setup that way.

Also note you need to escape the escape sequence (`'\\/'`) because what you're passing to the sh step is a string literal in groovy code. If you don't add that extra backslash, the line passed to the shell to be interpreted by it will be `echo ${git_branch_name////_}`, which it won't understand.

But there are other issues as well. First, assigning the output of the sh step to `branch_name` as you do means `branch_name` will always equal null. To get the stdout from a line of shell code you need to pass the extra parameter `returnStdout: true` to sh:

```java
branch_name = sh (
    script: 'echo ${git_branch_name//\\//_}',
    returnStdout: true
).trim ()     // You basically always need to use trim, because the
              // stdout will have a newline at the end
```

For bonus points, we could wrap that sh call in a [closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html). I find myself using it often enough to make this a good idea.

```java
// Get it? `sh` out, "shout!"
def shout = { cmd -> sh (script: cmd, returnStdout: true).trim () }

//...

branch_name = shout 'echo ${git_branch_name//\\//_}'
```

But finally, the major problem is that bash (or whatever shell is actually spawned) doesn't have access to groovy variables. As far as it knows, `echo ${git_branch_name}` outputs an empty string, and therefore so does `echo ${git_branch_name//\//_}`.

You have a couple of choices. You could skip the creation of `.git/branch-name` and just immediately output the string-replaced result of `git rev-parse`:

```java
branch_name = shout 'name=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && echo ${name//\\//_}'
```

Or to simplify that further you could use groovy's string replace function rather than the bash syntax:

```java
branch_name = shout ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').replace ('/', '_')
```

Personally, I find the latter quite a bit more readable. YMMV. So bringing it all together at last:

```java
#!groovy

def shout = { cmd -> sh (script: cmd, returnStdout: true).trim () }

// Note that I'm not declaring any variables up here. They're not needed.
// But you can if you want, just to clearly declare the environment for
// future maintainers.

node ('Nodename') {
    stage ('checkout') {
        checkout (scm).$Branch_Param
        commit_id = shout 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'
        branch_name = shout ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').replace ('/', '_')

        echo commit_id
        echo branch_name
        echo "The most recent commit on branch ${branch_name} was ${commit_id}"
    }
}
```